# I cannot make log4net work in my web application :(

Tags: .net, asp.net, logging, log4net

I'm trying to set up log4net but I cannot make it work. I've put this in my Web.config:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net>
  <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logfile.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
    <maximumFileSize value="15000KB" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Then, in my code I execute:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Web.config")));
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("MainLogger");

if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
    log.Debug("lalala");
```

But nothing happens. I checked the "log" variable, and it contains a LogImpl object that has all the logging levels enabled. I get no error or configuration warning, I cannot see any file in the root, in the bin or anywhere.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: If you can debug this in Visual Studio, check the Output window when your app fires up. log4net outputs any information about configuration errors there.

Comment: Have you tried setting an absolute path for the `file` property? (e.g. `C:\logfile.log`)

Comment: In addition to the excellent answers below, you should only call Configure once for the lifetime of the app process, e.g. in Application Start in Global.asax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have this line in your AssemblyInfo.cs file?

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```

Also, you should consider the "typeof(YourClass)" approach used by Eric in his answer below. The first time I have upvoted an alternative answer to one of mine. :)

You don't have a TraceAppender defined.

You don't have a logger named "MainLogger" configured

```
<logger name="MainLogger">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
</logger>
```

Also, have a look [here](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/06/16/log4net.html?page=2)

Comment: But he does have a <root> defined, which is a catch-all/default.

Comment: Fair point. I'm in the habit of being quite specific. My answer is incorrect and I will update it as soon as I find the correct answer

Comment: Adding that, I get the lines duplicated, but if I remove the root, then it works fine! :P

Thanks!

Comment: That is good. Just remember that you will now have to always call that logger explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

Try to write:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

instead, since Web.config is the default location where Log4Net will look.

Otherwise, remove that entire line from your code and paste the following into your AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```

This will configure Log4Net at assembly level. Then in your code, just create a logger like this:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(YourFunkyClass));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need another method to configure log4net: `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()`.

Then it will read the web.config automatically.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html, under the ".config files" section.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution :

```
Configuration oConfiguration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(oRequest.ApplicationPath);

log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(oConfiguration.FilePath));
```